# How to test overlay?

Tags: flutter-test

I am testing overlay that shows up on button click. The overlay contains TextFormField (check for demo [here](https://self_storing_input.codemagic.app/#/)).

I am wandering if may be I should use more advanced testing framework.

This is the code:

```
await tester.tap(find.byType(IconButton));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextFormField), 'hi');
```

The test fails on the last line with message `Bad state: No element`.

It seems overlay got lost. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pump overlay fully, `pumpAndSettle` should be invoked two times.
Also golden screen shot is extremely helpful feature while debugging:

```
await tester.tap(find.byType(IconButton));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
await tester.pumpAndSettle();

await expectLater(
  find.byType(MaterialApp),
  matchesGoldenFile('overlay.png'),
);

await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextFormField), 'hi');
```

Run `flutter test --update-goldens` to generate goldens.